# How to Iterate List (e.g. ArrayList) in XSLT

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a List of String named as myList and 
  I want to set all the values in XSLT in a tag using iteration:-

```
<alpha>
... 
</alpha>
```

How is it possible to do it?

Comment: The mapping of language types in a host language like Java and the use of them inside XSLT/XPath depends on the particular XSLT processor you use. But in general you can only expect a mapping of Java numbers to XSLT numbers, Java Strings to XSLT strings, booleans to booleans and perhaps some XML tree nodes to XSLT nodes/node-sets.

Comment: If you use/move to XSLT 3 with Saxon 9.8 or later you can use http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmValue.html#makeSequence-java.lang.Iterable- to convert your Java `ArrayList<String>` to an XSLT/XPath sequence of strings `xs:string*` you can process as any sequence in XSLT/XPath (e.g. `xsl:apply-templates`, `xsl:for-each`, map operator `!`, `xsl:value-of`.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen, I am using XSLT1 here and want to know how to iterate the List of string and place it into tags, Please see the reference snippet here. <xsl:param name=''myList">   <xsl:for-each select=$myList> <alpha><xs:value-of select="." /> </alpha> </xsl:for-each>.    This is not working at all.

Comment: Why do you expect an XSLT processor to be able to process a Java ArrayList with an `xsl:for-each`? XSLT processes XML so chances are your XSLT 1.0 processor allows you to pass in an XML tree structure as a parameter you could iterate over in XSLT, meaning you would need to convert the ArrayList to an XML tree structure. But even that, whether it works with DOM or other trees, will depend on the particular XSLT processor you use and how it interfaces with Java and the other Java APIs.

Comment: The snippet for XSLT processor for transformation is:- TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
      Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File(xslPath));
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
         transformer.setParameter("myList",new ArrayList<>().add("ABC").add("XYZ")); Do i need to convert Arraylist values into some DOM or Node Structure before setting it to the transform?

Comment: @MartinHonnen The code snippet is working for single string values, Then what could be the way for list of string here.

Comment: As I said, it depends on the particular XSLT processor and its API and/or conversions and extensions which effort you need to take and which particular data structure you need. In the Java world I tend to use Saxon 9, for that I have linked to a method to convert any Java `Iterable<T>` like an `ArrayList<String>` to an XSLT 2/3 sequence of strings. But that is Saxon specific and API specific. For XSLT 1 processors like Xalan or Saxon 6 things are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 has no data structure in its data model to represent a sequence of strings; the only "collection" structure it supports is a node-set. If you're absolutely tied to XSLT 1.0, then you're going to have to wrap the strings as XML elements and pass in a document containing these elements.

But you're using Java, so you have access to XSLT 2.0 and XSLT 3.0 by installing Saxon, so it makes no sense to try and live with these restrictions. XSLT 2.0 greatly extends the set of data types supported (to include "sequence of strings" as one of the many possibilities), and XSLT 3.0 extends it further to include maps. Saxon's mappings from Java data types to XSLT/XPath data types include the possibility of converting a Java `List<String>` to an XPath `xs:string*`.

With Saxon, you can declare a parameter as expecting a list of strings:

```
<xsl:param name="in" as="xs:string*"/>
```

and you can then supply as the actual value a `List<String>`, which is converted as described here:

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensibility/functions/function-result

In XSLT you can then wrap these strings as elements (I've used XSLT 3.0 syntax here):

```
<xsl:for-each select="$in">
  <alpha>{.}</alpha>
</xsl:for-each>
```

[Disclaimer: I am the lead developer of Saxon]

Comment: Thanks Michael Kay and Martin Honnen, Will try to upgrade on XSLT 2.0 or 3.0